# What motivates a good proposal distribution for a target distribution? (Metropolis - Hasting sampling)

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

In Metropolis - Hasting sampling, the proposal distribution does not necessarily have to have a form similar to that of the target distribution from which attempts are made to sample from.
For one, I understand that a symmetrical choice of proposal kernel can vastly simplify the conditional proposal which yield a simple ratio of target distribution but this says more about the simplification of the acceptance ratio rather than the *goodness* of a proposal distribution to a target distribution.

What motivates our choice of proposal distribution for efficient sampling?

Comment: Tools for proposal comparison are efficient sample size and expected (square) jumping distance.

Comment: @Xi'an Am I correct to interpret your comment as "we cannot know a priori what proposal distribution is best for some target distribution"?

Comment: The ideal proposal is the target itself, with no burn-in and independence between the draws.